# git svn fetch retrieves the same Subversion revision multiple times for branches

Tags: git, git-svn

I am seeing git svn fetch repeatedly retrieve the same Subversion
revisions when it finds branches in my Subversion repository.  We are
using the standard Subversion repository layout, with top level
/trunk, /tags, and /branches directories (and the git repository was
created with 'git svn init -s').  However, the problematic branches are
often copies made from a subdirectory inside of trunk, instead of
trunk.

The git svn fetch output typically looks something like this:

```
r2537 = d5b22e956157af036d4112e42e8fb927e45758c8 (trunk)
        M       Enterprise/VC/libgc/SymbolVenue.cpp
r2538 = cfed4ca0491da0b732f32bfff72ba678450a0915 (trunk)
Found possible branch point: http://repo/prod_repos/trunk/Enterprise/VC => http://repo/prod_repos/branches/file_conversion, 2523
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/scripter@832):
expected path: branches/scripter@832
    real path: trunk/Enterprise/Python
Continuing ahead with trunk/Enterprise/Python
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: branches/trunk
    real path: trunk
Continuing ahead with trunk
Initializing parent: file_conversion@2523
        A       gc/QuoteService.cpp
        A       gc/TestSuite.h
        A       gc/quote_svc.pro
        A       gc/QuoteService.h
.....

r1 = d349ed8cb2d76596fe2b83224986275be4600fad (QuoteSvcFix442@2698)
        D       gc/FixMessageLogger.h
.....
r5 =
r19 =
r20 = 
.....
```

And we are back at revision 1.  git svn fetch then
continues to fetch revisions until it reaches the revision that
created the branch.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway for me to tell git svn fetch to
not retrieve revisions it has already pulled?

Comment: Good question (+1). That happens to me too, and seems like a waste of my time.

Comment: Blame SVN, which stores branches essentially as copies of the repository ;-) A bit of the history and inner workings is given by David Wheeler at http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/scm.html

Answer (score 74):

I noticed this question because I got the same error message:

```
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: branches/trunk
    real path: trunk
```

It turned out that .git/config had duplicate lines that seem to confuse git-svn, like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
...
    branches = project/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = project/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
    branches = project/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = project/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Removing those duplicates solved weird git-svn behaviour for me, and might as well for you. I'm not sure what caused git-svn to duplicate this information in the first place. I killed and continued the initial clone, this might be related?

Comment: I had this problem too. And I also killed the initial clone and restarted. Looks like probably is the cause...

Comment: Hmm. I had the same duplicate listings in my .git/config, but even after stopping, removing the dupes, and starting up again, the problem is still present. :(

Comment: The problem in my case, at least, isn't a duplicate entry in the svn-remote.  The problem is a bit more fundamental to the git-svn architecture.  In brief, git svn doesn't track directory or file renames, which means it has to refetch the history.  Eric Wong, the git svn author, has a better description [here](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-07/msg01665.html)

Comment: Same problem here. Each time you run `git svn clone -s https://project/repo project` it duplicates data in .git/config.

Comment: My problem was that I re-ran a `git svn clone` operation when it failed due to an HTTP hiccup.

Comment: @KamilDziedzic @markjaquith I had the same issue. Multiple `git svn clone` calls due to flakey network connection

Comment: I had the same problem and this helped to fix it. Any idea why it ended up like that in the first place?

Comment: I have an adjustment to suggest to this solution: instead of killing the initial clone and delete these lines _suspend_ it (CTRL-Z) instead.  THEN delete the lines. Then use `fg` to restart it again in the foreground. That seems to prevent the other problem of restarting the clone adding the lines back again.

Answer (score 10):

Removing duplicates still created an issue for me. Each time you rerun your clone command e.g. **git svn clone svn://.../svnroot --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout .** It adds two more lines to .git/config.
I had to remove all lines containing **branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*** and  **tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/***

Leaving config looking like below:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
        noMetadata = 1
        url = svn://.../svnroot
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
[svn]
        authorsfile = /home/users/denn/authors-transform.txt
~
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to migrate tags and branches from `SVN`. This is just a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

**git-svn appears to be repeatedly pulling the same revisions because you have tags in your SVN repository.** SVN's concept of a tag is slightly different from git's: [SVN tags are actually branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372321/best-practice-for-svn-tags/372429#372429) (thus [SVN tags are *copies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977/how-are-tags-made-in-subversion/40003#40003)).

Take a closer look at your output:

> `r1 = d349ed8cb2d76596fe2b83224986275be4600fad (QuoteSvcFix442@2698)`

Although the revision `r1 =` looks too familiar, the rest of the text probably differs. At a minimum, the tag name (in this case `QuoteSvcFix442@2698`) will not be the same.

**I think the only way to prevent this is by having git-svn skip the SVN tags.** If you can't live without the tags, you can also [convert the SVN 'tag' branches to real git tags](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/16/convert-git-svn-tag-branches-to-real-tags.html) (but you have to fetch all the tag branches, first!)

---

A related SO question with possible work-arounds: [Can Git-svn be used on large, branched repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029520/can-git-svn-be-used-on-large-branched-repositories)

Some discussion about this issue: [git-svn --tags should at least /try/ to handle tags as tags](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501761).

Answer (score 4):

If, at any point, the trunk of your repository existed at a different location in SVN, try specifying this location to additionally fetch in the repository's config file.  For example:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
... 
    fetch = project/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    fetch = previous/location/of/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk-old1
    fetch = another/location/of/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk-old2
    ...
```

For the project I was importing, there were many branches and tags that had been created from these previous locations.  Since these were branches/tags created from an 'unknown' place, git svn was throwing up its hands and just fetching all the history to find out.  (This approach still required a full fetch for each location, but that was MUCH faster than a full history fetch for every tag)