# git svn clone has been running for a very long time. Is there a way to prove it's not stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: windows, git, svn, cygwin

I ran `git svn clone` about 24 hours ago and it's still running without an end in sight.  When I `ls` the destination directory, there's nothing in there but a .git folder.  Is there a way to prove that this command is actually making progress and not stuck in an infinite loop?

I'm running this command on windows 7 with cygwin.

The part that concerns me the most is I keep seeing messages like this over and over again:

```
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk@8286):
expected path: branches/trunk@8286
    real path: OLD/branches/APP
Continuing ahead with OLD/branches/APP
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk@8287):
expected path: branches/trunk@8287
    real path: OLD/branches/APP
Continuing ahead with OLD/branches/APP
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/tags/1.1@8289):
expected path: tags/1.1@8289
    real path: OLD/trunk/APP
Continuing ahead with OLD/trunk/APP
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/tags/1.1@8289):
expected path: tags/1.1@8289
    real path: OLD/trunk/APP
Continuing ahead with OLD/trunk/APP
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/tags/1.1@8289):
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem. For me, the cause was [the problem pointed to in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140428/git-svn-fetch-retrieves-the-same-subversion-revision-multiple-times-for-branches).

Answer (score -3):

There is actually no way to do this. There is a proof in computer science about how it is not actually possible to tell if a program is in an infinite loop or not. This proof is known as the Halting problem. Here is a link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

It sound to me like you are downloading something huge. Do you know the size? If the git repo has tons of images (read 10,000+) and you have a slow connect then the time to clone does not seem unexpected. If your git repo is only a few Megs, then it sounds like you have a problem, but in that case the remote server would most likely not be returning that stream of errors. Does that make sense? What else do you know about this problem?